# "Urgent Results" from LG V30 Smart Cleaning

Tags: notifications, battery-life, lg

I have an LG V30 (on Verizon, but I doubt that's relevant) that's about a year old. A couple of weeks ago, it updated to Android 9.0 Pie. Ever since that update, about once every 48 hours, I've been getting a notification from something called "Smart Cleaning" that says

> **Battery draining app**
>
> Dropbox constantly ran in the background

If I click on the notification, my options are to restrict or uninstall Dropbox.

I'm perfectly happy with my device's battery life and would like Dropbox to continue running in the background. I've tried disabling notifications in the smart cleaning program's settings, but that's had no effect and the messages keep coming. I've also tried telling the phone to disable this notification permanently when it comes up, but it says "these notifications cannot be disabled". These are starting to get on my nerves, so what can I do to get rid of this recurring message? For reference, I've included an image of the screen that pops up when I click on the notification.

[image: Smart Cleaning App]